# How to securely connect to VPS application which expects HTTP connection

Tags: linux, http, security, networking, https

I have a Virtual Private Server (VPS) running Debian 10. On this server there is an application (its code rather cannot be modified) which creates an open TCP/IP port (let's say 6000). The application has a simple database with users and passwords and all incoming messages MUST be HTTP.

Obviously, at this point I am more than worried about the security of the communication (which in fact does not exist due to the plain nature of HTTP).

My first thought would be to drop all packets on the mentioned port for the eth0 iface (which is exposed to Internet), create OpenVPN server on my VPS and connect to this VPN all clients that would like to use my application. The problem here is that these clients will most likely be Android devices and it will not be possible to upload certificates for each device and do other configuration magic to establish the VPN connection. I also would not like to implement OpenVPN in a dedicated Android app.

My another though was that there is maybe an application which I would start on the VPS and it would implement such logic:

```
Android app <--HTTPS--> UnknownApp(on VPS side) <--HTTP--> port6000(My original unsafe app also on the VPS side)
```

Is it feasible to implement such scenario? Ofc I could write such app on my own but I would prefer to use tested and reliable solutions.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but the sane way of going about this would be to make the app that requires HTTP only listen on the loop-back interface, and have e.g. apache or nginx on the box, listening to the outside world (standard https ports or whatever you choose) and acting as a reverse proxy and passing requests down to the app on port 6000 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application you are looking for is `stunnel`. It does exactly what you described, it is well tested, based on well-known libraries, and production ready.